# Dataset for multivariate changepoint detection

Tags: statistics, dataset, multivariate-testing

I'm in my last year's way to a master's degree and my final project is about detecting changes in multivariate datasets (changepoint detection). I was looking for interesting datasets but couldn't find any :/ One of my ideas was for example number of some kinds of fishes in the same spot (like predators and herbivores) or changes in air's ratio. Also was looking for some astronomy datasets (maybe signals from many specters of light from the same spot?

Do u have any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic for SO. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific domain constraint, I'd suggest to focus on the dataset. As soon as you find one that is suitable for you, it's done. It's harder to look for a specific topic dataset.
You can look into [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets) or in [MLR](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php).